# webview_flutter not working with flutter 2 (was working pre flutter 2)

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using a WebView to simply display a Privacy Policy and Terms within an app.  This was working with the latest Flutter version prior to upgrading to Flutter 2 today.

The error I'm getting is this:
/Users/mymac/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-2.0.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:385:23: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true;

My iOS target is 10.0

My usage for WebView seems pretty basic and the error appears related to the package itself.

My usage is simply:

```
  child: WebView(
    initialUrl: aURL,
    ),
```

I've tried with:

```
webview_flutter: ^2.0.2
```

and

```
webview_flutter: ^1.0.7 // -- version used prior to Flutter 2
```

I'm hoping someone knows the solution to this or can point me in a better direction.  I'm open to any suggestions.  Thanks

UPDATE: It seems it's trying to compile for iOS 9.0 instead of 10.0.  See attached 2 images.  How can I force this to 10.0?
[MinimumOS Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAIor.png)
[error showing compiling for 9.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Dpv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out.  Not exactly sure which step specifically solved the problem but here's the steps I took.

1. Stopped Xcode (I had already done this and a flutter clean)
2. Changed the sdk in pubspec.yaml to ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
3. Pub get
4. Loaded dependencies
5. flutter clean
6. Chose a different Simulator

Then I tried the example code and it worked.  Tried my app and it worked (well, after correcting some null safety issues).